# Ada Actual for this must be a variable in out mode

Tags: ada

I am making a program in Ada for Data Structures and Algorithms class.

My current problem is the error *'actual for "this" must be a variable'*
I did some looking around and I read about it being because of *in out* mode, but I'm not entirely grasping why it's happening to me I guess.

The Examples I seen made sense but I guess since it's my coding I'm just not seeing it?

```
Procedure AddUnmarked(g:Grid; this:Linked_List_Coord.List_Type; c:Cell) is
      cNorth : Cell := getCell(g, North(c));
      cEast  : Cell := getCell(g, East(c));
      cSouth : Cell := getCell(g, South(c));
      cWest  : Cell := getCell(g, West(c));
   Begin
         if CellExists(g, cNorth) and not cNorth.IsMarked then
            Linked_List_Coord.Append(this, cNorth.Coords);
         elsif CellExists(g, cEast) and not cEast.IsMarked  then
            Linked_List_Coord.Append(this, cEast.Coords);
         elsif CellExists(g, cSouth) and not cSouth.IsMarked  then
            Linked_List_Coord.Append(this, cSouth.Coords);
         elsif CellExists(g, cWest) and not cWest.IsMarked  then
            Linked_List_Coord.Append(this, cWest.Coords);
         end if;
   End AddUnmarked;
```

before "this" is passed to the function it is a Linked_List of my self defined type Coord (2 integers). It is initialized and has had a Coordinate pair added to it before the list is passed to the function above in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What it means is that the list cannot be modified unless you are passing it as a modifiable parameter, that is, `in out`.

To elaborate, think of `LIST_TYPE` as being a handle to a tagged-type object; in order to ensure that `LIST_TYPE` is valid you need to pass it in via an `in` parameter (or create/manipulate a local object), but to pass out your results you need an `out` parameter.

So, in order to do your operations on an already-existing object {and get the results back} you need `in out`.

Comment: *facepalm* thank you, I really do feel retarded lol. I had in out on the List's function but not on that so it never came to mind that was problem.

Comment: No problem. Also I elaborated on it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

In Ada, subroutine parameters all have a usage mode associated with them. The available modes are `in`, `out`, and `in out`*. If you don't specify a mode, (like you didn't in your code), then it defaults to `in` only.

The modes specify what you can do with that parameter on the inside of the subprogram. If you want to read a value passed in from outside the routine, it must have `in` on it. If you want to write to the parameter (and/or possibly have it read outside the routine), then it must have `out` on it.

Since none of your parameters have `out` on them, you cannot write to any of them.

(* - There's another possible mode: `access`, but that's an advanced topic).

Comment: On the topic of `access` parameter modes, is there anything wherein they're required? I do know that the GNAT JVM Ada-compiler makes pretty heavy use of them in the imported [library] specifications.

Comment: @Shark8 - If you have a good question like that, perhaps you should ask it as a SE question. :-)

Comment: Ok, asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146219/what-is-the-usefulness-of-the-access-parameter-mode